# add vector to multi dimensional array matlab

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, matrix, bsxfun

Thanks in advance for the help.

Suppose I have a multi D array x such that

```
x(:,:,1) = [1 2; 3 4];
x(:,:,2) = [5 6; 7 8];
```

and a matrix y such that

```
y = [1 2; 5 6];
```

I would like to add the first row of y to each row of x(:,:,1) and the second row of y to each element of x(:,:,2).  This will produce an array z such that

```
z(:,:,1) = [2 4; 4 6];
z(:,:,2) = [10 12; 12 14];
```

In reality (not the example I am giving) I would like to do this operation on a very large multi D array x and a very large matrix y.  I therefore want to do this as efficiently as possible.

The naive approach would be to use for loops to do this, but this would not be efficient what-so-ever.  I believe that an efficient approach would be to incorporate bsxfun to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to figure out an approach.  y and x can and be restructured to accomplish this task as long as the same z is produced and, most importantly, the amount of time needed to build z is less than the for loop approach.

I was able to find [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8773-multiple-matrix-multiplications--with-array-expansion-enabled) which does what I want, but only for multiplication and not summation.  I could modify this code to do what I want but I feel as though with summation that there has to be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and a little bit of [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
z = bsxfun(@plus, x, permute(y, [3 2 1]));
```

The key is to properly rearrange the dimensions of `y` so that the singleton expansion performed by `bsxfun` gives you the desired result.